# How do I pass arguments to $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery

How do I pass data to a $.ajax() call? I'd like to pass a GUID (string) and, in another case, an array containing an integer and a string.

The code below works fine but I need to pass some arguments for processing. Thanks!

```
function btnAdd_onclick() {
            $.ajax({
                "url": "Add.aspx",
                "type": "get",
                "success": function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    $("body").append(response);

                },
                "error": function (response) {
                    alert("Error: " + response);
                }
            })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) parameter in the options hash:

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/pancakes/house',
    data: { 'where': [ 'is' ] },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: But how is the data array, or an individual element 'passed' to $.ajax({})??
If $.ajax is included in 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
then it is run as soon as the document is ready, what about if I want to call it from another function so that, for example I can call the $.ajax function multiple times?

Comment: @john Not sure I understand your question. `$.ajax` is a function like any other so you call it like any other function when you have the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is using the `data` parameter with an object containing the key-value pairs, e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...
    type: ...
    data: {
        guid: ...
        param2: ...
    },
    ...
});
```

jQuery will wrap that object up into `key1=value1&key2=value2` etc format.

If any of the values are arrays then the processing is slightly different - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: this is the best way ... but it needs to be stringified ... the encoding will be incorrect if you just passed in a json object like that.

Comment: that's not a JSON object, it's a normal JS object and jQuery will correctly (and automaticall) URIencode and pack the key-value pairs therein.

Comment: you are right ... I forgot that it needs to be string/string pairs to be json ... but I have never had it successfully encode it correctly. I have always had to rely upon the JSON.stringify() method to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it with a query string?

```
"url": "Add.aspx" + '?ID=' + [VARIABLE],
```

Comment: you can, but you shouldn't - that's what the `data` parameter is for.